# Does Picasso library save image to the cache?

Tags: android, image, picasso

I work on an android application, and I would like to clarify, does [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library save the processing image to the cache?

If it does not, how can I force Picasso to save the image to the cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Picasso automatically caches images. You can check where Picasso loaded an image from by calling

```
setIndicatorsEnabled(true)
```

on the Builder.

Comment: Sorry for my qestion, i beginner programmer but where its Builder?

Comment: I add code in my adapter: `Picasso.with(context).setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
  Picasso.with(context).load(ArrayListNews.get(position).getImage()).into(holder.imageview);` but image not loader when i have not internet

Comment: What does the Method getImage() return? Of course you need to have internet the first time you load the images. http://square.github.io/picasso/static/debug.png

Comment: Its work, but wen i close apps and then open app image no load